# Toggle List Box Display In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a List Box in my WPF app. Here is the xaml code:

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding lbIsVisible}">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <CheckBox>
                <TextBlock>CITRUS EXPRESS</TextBlock>
            </CheckBox>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem>
            <CheckBox>
                <TextBlock>APL CALIFORNIA</TextBlock>
            </CheckBox>
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem>
            <CheckBox>
                <TextBlock>IS JAPAN</TextBlock>
            </CheckBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="chkSelectVessel" Checked="chkSelectVessel_Checked">
        <TextBlock Text="Select Vessel"></TextBlock>
    </CheckBox>
```

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of the list box.
Here is the C# code.

```
public partial class ConfigSetting : Window
{
    public string lbIsVisible { get; set; }

    public ConfigSetting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        lbIsVisible = "Hidden";
    }

    private void chkSelectVessel_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.lbIsVisible = "Visible";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can any one point where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where you are defined `chkSelectVessel_Checked` event?

Comment: updated the xaml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`INotifyPropertyChanged Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
public partial class ConfigSetting : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string lbIsVisible;

    public string LbIsVisible
    {
        get { return lbIsVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (lbIsVisible != value)
            {
                lbIsVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LbIsVisible");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ConfigSetting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LbIsVisible = "Hidden";
        DataContext = this;
    }        

    private void chkSelectVessel_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LbIsVisible = "Visible";
    }

    private void ChkSelectVessel_OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LbIsVisible = "Hidden";
    }
}
```

And in the XAML bind to `LbIsVisible` property:

```
<ListBox Visibility="{Binding LbIsVisible}">
```

Also add `Unchecked` event to your `CheckBox` :

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
  x:Name="chkSelectVessel" Checked="chkSelectVessel_Checked" Unchecked="ChkSelectVessel_OnUnchecked">
```